# How to do auto-renew feature in flutter firebase - In App Purchase

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, subscription

I'm using in-app-purchases subscription in flutter and for the backend, I have used firebase realtime database.

What I'm doing is.. when a customer makes the purchase, it adds the expiration date on firebase realtime database but how to handle the auto-renew feature, how would I listen to it and re-update the expiration date on auto-renewal day

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).
You can add auto update database there using cron.
But this feature is paid

Alternatively you can migrate to [Supabase](https://supabase.com/)
Also there is guide to migrate from firebase to supabase.

Comment: is there any listener or anything in inapppurchase library or any another way to do it?

Comment: so you use inapppurchase package ? 

i saw the documentation and there is the stream there : you can listen through the streams 

https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase#:~:text=class%20_MyAppState%20extends,super.dispose()%3B%0A%20%20%7D

Comment: i have already used this subscription listener but doesnt help cause it not listening to auto renew.

Comment: if you want to handle auto renew to database, u should use cloud function. 
the listener just to listen the updated status